# AWS Lambda does not resolve all promises before terminating

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, aws-lambda

I'm struggling with a simple AWS Lambda function that should publish some messages to a SNS topic.

My email address is subscribed to the topic and the subscription has been confirmed.

The topic is in the same region as my lambda function.

The function is associated to an IAM role that has two policies attached:

1. the default policy AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
2. another policy that allows the function to write to my SNS topic

Policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sns:Publish",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my function code, developed on Cloud9.

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sns = new AWS.SNS({region:'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

    const apiResponse = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(['one', 'two', 'three']), 500)
    });

    const messages = await apiResponse;

    const promises = [];

    messages.forEach(txt => {
       promises.push(sns.publish({
           Message: txt,
           Subject: txt,
           TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:MyWebsiteContactForm'
       }).promise());
    });

    console.log(promises);

    Promise.all(promises,
        function (values) {
            console.log(values);
            callback(null, values);
        },
        function(err) {
            console.error(Error(err));
            callback(Error(err));
        }
    );
};
```

The result of executing this code is just this expected output, but it never logs anything inside `Promise.all()`.

```
[ Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> } ]
```

It's like if Lambda terminates before resolving the promises, but I cannot figure out why. I used `Promise.all()` as suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html#multiple-promises)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Voted to close as this is a duplicate of 99999 questions on StackOverflow already. Examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31633912/how-to-wait-for-async-actions-inside-aws-lambda, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54143931/aws-lambda-seems-exiting-before-completion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563173/aws-lambda-ending-early-without-any-explicit-return-or-callback

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are using `async` keyword on your handler, lambda will await for it and exit. Your `async` function doesn't contains any `await`, so it will run immediately.

To fix it, you can:

1. Remove the `async` keyword, so Lambda will wait for the `calllback` call, or;
2. Use await to your `Promise.all()`, as shown:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const sns = new AWS.SNS({region:'eu-west-1'});

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

    const promises = []; 

    ['one', 'two', 'three'].forEach(txt => {
       promises.push(sns.publish({
           Message: txt,
           Subject: txt,
           TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY'
       }).promise());
    });

    console.log(promises);

    try {
        let values = await Promise.all(promises);
        // do any transformations here
        return values;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        // deal with errors here or re-throw the error if you need that
        // the lambda function results in error too.
        throw(err);
        // Or
        return "something went wrong";
    }
};
```

For more details see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually use async code in my function, I forgot to remove the async token from the function handler. I also added a fake async code in my question shortly before your reply. Maybe you want to update your answer. Anyway I'm accepting it because your point is correct